# Best nntp to web gateway?

Tags: nntp, usenet

My company uses usenet groups on an internal nntp server and I would like to add a web server to this that would allow the usual browsing and searching but in addition provide an archive of old messages that may have expired on the server. This is mainly for searching the archives so ability to post is not important.

Can anyone recommend a piece of software the would act as such a gateway? Most of the stuff I found on Google appears to be either no longer maintained or doesn't offer the archive ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmane seems to be nice. You could also look into a NNTP -> Email thing and use any of the available email web archive software.

Answer (score 2):

How about FUDforum? For details see http:///fudforum.org/